# How do i remove an object from an array list after a mouse event?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, object, jpanel

When i click my mouse in the JPanel, the program creates a green dot and displays a counter on screen for the number of dots. The dots are in an array list saved as objects. I'm attempting to alter this code so that if i click within the radius of an existing dot (each with a radius of 6) that dot will disappear from the list and be deleted from the screen.

(Before you ask, yes you may recognize this as a homework problem and no I'm not trying to cheat)

I figured that this involves creating a for loop to scan for objects within the array, looking to pick up objects that the pointer may have clicked on. However I am confused as how to accomplish this exactly

Thanks!

```
public class DotsPanel extends JPanel
{
   private final int SIZE = 6;  // radius of each dot

   private ArrayList<Point> pointList;// "Point"s are objects that rep. the x & y coordinates of a dot





   public DotsPanel()
   {
      pointList = new ArrayList<Point>();

      addMouseListener (new DotsListener());

      setBackground(Color.black);
      setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
   }




   public void paintComponent(Graphics page)
   {
      super.paintComponent(page);

      page.setColor(Color.green);

      for (Point spot : pointList)
         page.fillOval(spot.x-SIZE, spot.y-SIZE, SIZE*2, SIZE*2);



      page.drawString("Count: " + pointList.size(), 5, 15);//draws the image of the counter




   }




   private class DotsListener implements MouseListener
   {


      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event)
      {
         pointList.add(event.getPoint());
         repaint();
      }


      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {}
      public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {}
      public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {}
      public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {}
   }
}
```

Comment: pointList.contains(event.getPoint()) - Returns true if arraylist contains the value, otherwise false

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, you'll need to modify the implementation of `mousePressed()` in `DotsListener` because you don't want to unconditionally add a new dot on every click. I'd suggest changing it to something like this:

```
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event)
  {
     Point hitDot = getHitDot(event);
     if (hitDot == null) {
         // no dots hit
         pointList.add(event.getPoint());
     } else {
         // hit a dot
         pointList.remove(hitDot);
     }
     repaint();
  }
```

Since this is homework, I'm not going to write `getHitDot` for you. I will say that you have the correct idea: loop through all the elements of `pointList`, testing each `Point` and immediately returning it if is within a distance `SIZE` of the mouse press coordinates. You can use the [Euclidean distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) formula to do the hit test for each dot.